# Django: how to properly use UserProfile? (Django auth extra information)

Tags: python, django, authentication

i finally can make my Django+Auth app works. I add the extra information to the user as the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) say. Now, i've a simple question. When i'm building a model that is related to the user, which user should i relate to? To auth.models.User or to my accounts.UserProfile?

An example: I've a model for Product, and the Product belongs to a user. Which would be the best option:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(auth.models.User)
```

or

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(accounts.UserProfile)
```

I'm currently using auth.models.User, becouse i can issue a get_profile, but some friend told me that i was wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: "but some friend told me that i was wrong".  Get documentation from that friend.  It appears they're just making things up.

Comment: Haha, you're right. But, you know, people use to do things different. That's why i consider asking this here, where many oppinions are told.

Comment: "people use to do things different"  True.  "That's why i consider asking this here".  Don't do that first.  Always get facts first.  Check with Google second.  Ask here third.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing the right thing.

UserProfile is just an extension of the User model. 
And logically you're making a relation of a object with an object, not a relation of a object with some extra information.

Also, as you mentioned, you can always issue the 'get_profile' to get the extra data.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users and specifically "each User object will have a method -- get_profile() -- which returns the instance of the user profile model associated with that User."